# How to pass argument that inherits base class and implements interface?

Tags: kotlin

I need to pass in the method an object which class inherits from base class and implements my interface. I wrote it below in pseudo Kotlin syntax:

```
fun destroyBrains(justKillMe: BaseClass & IListener) {
}
```

Is it possible in Kotlin? (I mean not to introduce a new class that will implements `BaseClass` and `IListener`)

Comment: @MadhuBhat, I see, thank you for answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set multiple upper bounds on generic types using the `where` clause:

```
fun <T> destroyBrains(justKillMe: T)
    where T : BaseClass,
          T : IListener {

}
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, maybe this will be useful.